# PHP script for calculating Krippendorff's Alpha

Tags: php, alpha

I can't find any PHP script to compute [Krippendorff's Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff's_Alpha). I need this for a project I'm working on, but the only things that I was able to find online are either written in Python (that I know nothing of) or are for SAS/SPSS software suites.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and Perl syntax are quite similar. Here's the [Perl script](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/Research/nle/arrau/interval-alpha.perl.pl) from the [ALPHA](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/Research/nle/arrau/alpha.html) resource page. I am sure you know how to convert the for loops/etc in Perl to PHP. If you are unsure about the syntax, search the Perl docs or internet and find the equivalent in PHP. You should be able to develop an equivalent PHP script by looking at the sample Perl one.

Comment: Thanks! That's where I got the other scripts but I simply overlooked the perl script. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class. I used it worked

https://github.com/wikimedia/wikimedia-discovery-discernatron/blob/master/src/RelevanceScoring/KrippendorffAlpha.php

Answer (score 0):

This is my [javascript library](https://github.com/tanbt/krippendorff-alpha) for Krippendorff's Alpha. The detail instruction could be found in README.md. Hope it could help.